# Parabolic points and curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have problems to solve this exercise:
Let $p$ be a point of an oriented surface $S$ and assume that there is a neighborhood $U$
of $p$ in $S$ all points of which are parabolic. Prove that the (unique) asymptotic
curve through $p$ is an open segment of a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice question. Here's a hint: Assume you have a parametrization where the $u$- and $v$-curves are lines of curvature. Apply the Mainardi-Codazzi equations to deduce that an appropriate Christoffel symbol vanishes. This, in turn, will tell you that the parameter curve is a line segment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't undertando how to apply Mainardi-Codazzi equations.

Comment: In what form do you have those equations? I don't know the notation your course is using. But you should be able to deduce something from the fact that the principal curvature along the $u$-curves, being identically $0$, therefore has derivative $0$ as well.

Comment: If $(L,M,N)$ is the second fundamental form, I know the equations as: $L_v-M_u= L \Gamma^1_{12}+M(\Gamma^2_{12}-\Gamma^1_{11})-N\Gamma^2_{11}$ and $M_v-N_u= L \Gamma^1_{22}+M(\Gamma^2_{22}-\Gamma^1_{12})-N\Gamma^2_{12}$

Comment: So, with a parametrization such as I suggested, what are $L$ and $M$?

Comment: The derivative...

Comment: I know what they are. I'm asking you to compute here. Reread my answer and make sure you know what lines of curvature are.